# How do i get this output? (For loop)

Tags: c#, loops

I'm trying to get the end result:

> 1
>   2 1
>   3 2 1
>   4 3 2 1

This is what I have tried so far and I have the shape but I need the number to decrease. How do I solve this? I understand that I have to subtract somewhere but it compromises the shape.

```
public static void DrawDiamond(int size)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 1; i <= size; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j < i; j++)
        {
           Console.Write(j);

        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

}
```

My current results is this:

> 1
>   1 2
>   1 2 3
>   1 2 3 4

Comment: a hint: if you want the number to decrease, consider subtraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hello JeremyM,**

## Logic

```
int i, j;
for (i = 1; i <= no_of_row; i++)
{
    for (j = i; j>=1; j--)
    {
       Console.Write(j);

    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

## Solution

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
       int i, j;
        for (i = 1; i <= no_of_row; i++)
        {
            for (j = i; j>=1; j--)
            {
               Console.Write(j);

            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

For Example:
no_o_rows = 5 so output,

```
1
21
321
4321
54321
```

I hope my answer is helpful.
If any query so comment please.

Answer (score 0):

Print value of i-j+1 insted of only j

Answer (score 0):

Or if you prefer to work with Linq:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 5).ToList().ForEach(x =>
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    Enumerable.Range(1, x).Reverse().ToList().ForEach(y => Console.Write(y));
});
```

which produces:

```
1
21
321
4321
54321
```

Answer (score 0):

This works too:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
    Enumerable
        .Range(1, 4)
        .Select(x => String.Join(" ", Enumerable.Range(1, x).Reverse()))));
```

I get:

```
1
2 1
3 2 1
4 3 2 1
```